# Are my calculations correct?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

Solve the following system using Gaussian elimination:

$ x + 4y + z = 0\\
    4x + 13y + 7z = 0\\
    7x + 22y + 13z = 1$

This is what I have done:

```
Augmented Matrix:    1 4   1    0
                   4  13   7    0  
                   7   22   13   1
```

$ R_2 - 4R_1 = R_2$ and $R_3 - 7R_1 = R_3$

```
                   1    4    1    0
                   0   -3    3    0
                   0   -6    6    1
```

$-1/3R_2 = R_2$

```
                   1    4    1    0
                   0    1   -1    0
                   0   -6    6    1
```

$R_3 + 6R_2 = R_3$

```
                   1    4    1    0
                   0    1   -1    0
                   0    0    0    1
```

By what I understand, the last row means $0x + 0y + 0z = 1$
This is incorrect so this means that the system is **inconsistent**
Have I made a mistake somewhere with my calculations or am I misunderstanding something? Or is the system really inconsistent and does that mean that it has no valid solution?

-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the system is indeed inconsistent. The rank of the original matrix (non-augmented) is $2$, which means that the system either has infinitely many solutions or it has zero solutions. Your manipulation shows that it has zero solutions.

Comment: Thank you very much... What do you mean by the "rank" of the original matric? And how did you get to the rank being 2? @5xum

Comment: [Rank](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)), to put simply for now, is the number of non-zero rows in the non-augmented matrix. Chances are you will learn more about it further in a linear algebra course.

Comment: "number of non-zero rows in the non-augmented matrix *written in Row Echelon Form*" I should have said.